# Query related to MDX performance

Tags: mdx, performance-testing

We are facing an issue with one of the MDX queries.
If we use date selector in the Range  in the where clause it takes 6 secs to execute else if we use comma  as a separator, it takes around 1 sec.

Is there a way to modify the query and improve the performance by giving the range in the where clause. Kindly let us know your inputs on the same.

Example 1  With comma separator

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.X AS SUM({[User].[column].CURRENTMEMBER},[Measures].[# User Count]) 
    SELECT NON EMPTY 
   UNION({[User].[column].[ALL]}, 
   Generate(Hierarchize([User].[Column].[ALL]) 
   AS [XL_Filter_Set_0], TopCount(Except(DrilldownLevel([XL_Filter_Set_0].Current 
   AS [XL_Filter_HelperSet_0],,0,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS), [XL_Filter_HelperSet_0]) 
   , 5,  [Measures].[# User Count])) 
   )DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS  , Measures.X  ON COLUMNS 
  FROM [Activity] where 
  ({[Date].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year Name].&[2012],[Date].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year Name].&[2013], 
  [Date].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year Name].&[2014]}, 
  {[Activity Type].[Activity Hierarchy].[All]})
```

Example 2  Without comma separator but we have given the range

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.X AS SUM({[User].[column].CURRENTMEMBER},[Measures].[# User Count]) 
    SELECT NON EMPTY 
      UNION({[User].[column].[ALL]}, 
         Generate(Hierarchize([User].[Column].[ALL]) 
            AS [XL_Filter_Set_0], TopCount(Except(DrilldownLevel([XL_Filter_Set_0].Current 
             AS [XL_Filter_HelperSet_0],,0,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS), [XL_Filter_HelperSet_0]) 
            , 5,  [Measures].[# User Count])) 
              )DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS  , Measures.X  ON COLUMNS 
          FROM [Activity] where 
  ({[Date].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year Name].&[2012]:[Date].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year Name].&[2014]}, 
  {[Activity Type].[Activity Hierarchy].[All]})
```

Regards,
Nancy

Answer (score 0):

instead of using range in `WHERE` try use Range in `FROM`

```
from (
select ([Date].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year Name].&[2012]:[Date].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year Name].&[2014]) on Columns From [Activity])
```